# How does alkaline pipe cleaner corrode plumbing?

Tags: corrosion

The siphon of my bathroom sink was clogged up again, and I became curious on why it clogged up so quickly each time. So I decided to open the pipe and was shocked to see the plumbing like this:

[image]

Initially I thought it was mold, but the white stuff has is rather solid and it might be some sort of salt. Inside I found two three EUR cent coins which have a steel core and a copper coating. They were heavily corroded and seemed to have fused with the inner wall of the pipe. The copper coating was open and the steel core visible.

[image]

When I put it back together, the pipe cracked when I applied some torque with the wrench. The wall must have become really thin. The crash has a rust color, and the whole inside of the pipe also has this typical rust red.

[image]

I guess that the pipe is made from steel with a chromium coating.

A prior tenant has excessively used pipe cleaner, this highly alkaline granulate. So we have a steel pipe, a chromium coating, copper coins with a steel core, lots of alkaline granulate and hand soap.

My chemistry education unfortunately stopped in high school, but I would be really interested in the following things?

- What could the stuff on the outside be? Some sodium iron chromium salt?
- I've read that the pipe cleaner is really bad for plumbing (that's why I never use that stuff), but I don't understand how say NaOH would interact with solid Fe. How does that work?
- Could the copper coins have made the rust process of the pipe worse?

Comment: Martin, The key problem is we do not know the composition of the pipe. It is certainly a low quality piping material. Also there is not guarantee that the previous tenant used a particular type of drain opener. Both acids and bases attack metals (slowly or rapidly). The situation is more complex when you have (unknown) alloys.

Comment: As @AChem states, it's not a simple question to answer. For example, did the drain cleaner contain aluminum, which releases hydrogen and causes embrittlement? Was the pipe aluminum or zinc "pot metal", both attacked by drain cleaner? Was there electrolytic corrosion? usw...

Comment: I see! Unfortunately I don't know what metal the pipe is. Local hardware stores sell these pipes in steel with chrome coating, my landlord mentioned aluminum. And I don't know the type of pipe cleaner, Then I guess in either case the corrosion is likely to happen, but the details depend on too many unknowns. Thanks for your time!